# Git Status/Diff Ignores Changed Files with UNchanged Timestamps

Tags: git

I have a bedeviling problem.  My git repository contains files that were damaged from hard drive corruption.  That left some files with trashed contents, but with *unchanged timestamps*.  In fact the full `stat` information shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Nothing I've been able to find has even hinted at how to make git detect these files so that I can restore them from the repository.  Git seems to be purely looking at the timestamps.  If I `touch` one of the corrupted files, `git status` picks it up right away and I can check it out no problem.  The problem: how to get a list of files to revert.

Edit: Actually it's more than just getting the list.  `git checkout -- corrupt_file` will *not* restore it from the repo.  Git sees the unchanged stat info and "helpfully" declines to do the useless work of copying an unchanged file.  So I also need to force git to check out the good version of the file.

I have tried various flags on `git status` and `git diff` *and* TortoiseGit.  I even tried `git update-index --really-refresh`.  Nothing.  A full `git checkout` is the last last resort.

This is git 2.17.0 on Cygwin 3.0.7 on Windows 7 SP1 64 bit.

Thanks.

Comment: I first thought of deleting every file but `.git` folder and then `git checkout .`, but on second thought I think it might be destructive if `.git` folder is also corrupted. Of course I'm assuming there's something that is not pushed to remote repo - if not just re-cloning will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes this is a local only repository.  And yeah there could be some some .git corruption I'm not aware of.

Comment: Given hard-drive corruption, I would (1) `git clone --mirror` the repository onto a **different computer**; (2) use `git fsck` on the clone even though the process of cloning should serve as a check; (3) either just `touch` every file, or diff (not necessarily *git* diff) the work-tree on the damaged machine against the one in the new mirror clone on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a full checkout (which should be a good first step unless the repository is huge and your disk space limited), you could try and do a [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

If you know of a sequence of characters which:

- are not likely to be in a regular file
- are often seen in your trashed content

you could, with `git grep`, check if any file is listed, and checkout those.